# Error : RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop2

I am trying to do nested operation inside a RDD transformation, and is throwing error.

> Error : RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations

I am using IndexedRDD to update from another RDD but not able to as IndexedRDD is updatable. Here is the code . How can I achieve this ?

```
for ((key, value) <- mapped1) 
  indexed = indexed.put(key, value)
```

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: @tuxdna, it's in the subject line. OP, as it says, you can't invoke transformations on an RDD inside a transform for another RDD. What is the computation you're trying to do? There will be another way of doing it.  At present, it seems just a copy...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error, only the driver node is able to perform transformations and actions on RDDs. It seems that your code is likely executing on a worker node (e.g. inside of another transformation or action). It seems like you are trying to construct a `union` of the two RDDs, so I'd recommend looking at the `union` operator and seeing if it meets your needs.